# Issues in adding text to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below, is a `ggplot` with two distributions.
I want to add mean of both distribution in each `facet`. I have few issues -

1. The texts containing mean values overlap
2. I want to use separate labels for each mean. For ex - "mean_1 = " and "mean_2 = "
3. Additionally, how can I add a boundary of same color on distribution to clearly see the outline of each distribution.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

# distribution and categories
distribution <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
category_1 <- c(rep("A", 500), rep("B", 500))
category_2 <- c(rep("C", 250), rep("D", 250),
                rep("C", 250), rep("D", 250))
category_3 <- factor(sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 1000))


# create tibble
tbl <- tibble(distribution, category_1, category_2, category_3)

text_summary = tbl %>% 
  group_by(category_1, category_2, category_3) %>%
  summarize(mean = round(mean(distribution), 2)) %>%
  mutate(lab = paste0("mean = ", mean))

# create histogram
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = distribution,
           fill = category_3)) + 
  geom_histogram(position = "identity",
                 alpha = 0.5) + 
  facet_grid(category_1 ~ category_2) + 
  # add mean values as text
  geom_text(data = text_summary, 
            aes(label = lab, 
                x = 2, 
                y = 10),
            color = "blue3") +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go through your points for some comments before getting to the code.

1. You can dodge the text by adding or subtracting some value depending on the group. Below, I've used `as.numeric(category_3) * 1.5` to offset the text somewhat.
2. You can add some identifier in the `mutate()` call. Depending whether you want just 'mean_1' and 'mean_2' or a mean for every combination of your categories, you can uncomment the `ungroup()` line in the code below.
3. You might be looking for `geom_step()` to give an outline to a histogram.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.1

# distribution and categories
distribution <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
category_1 <- c(rep("A", 500), rep("B", 500))
category_2 <- c(rep("C", 250), rep("D", 250),
                rep("C", 250), rep("D", 250))
category_3 <- factor(sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 1000))


# create tibble
tbl <- tibble(distribution, category_1, category_2, category_3)

text_summary = tbl %>% 
  group_by(category_1, category_2, category_3) %>%
  summarize(mean = round(mean(distribution), 2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% # Comment this line out if you only want mean_1 and mean_2
  mutate(lab = paste0("mean_", seq_along(mean), " = ", mean))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'category_1', 'category_2'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

# create histogram
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = distribution)) + 
  geom_histogram(
    aes(fill = category_3),
    position = "identity", alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_step(
    aes(colour = category_3),
    stat = "bin", direction = "mid"
  ) +
  facet_grid(category_1 ~ category_2) + 
  # add mean values as text
  geom_text(data = text_summary,
            aes(label = lab,
                x = 2,
                y = 12 - as.numeric(category_3) * 1.5),
            color = "blue3") +
  theme_bw()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Is there a better to draw histograms because it is very difficult to appreciate the shape of each distribution due to significant overlap

Comment: I typically set `alpha = 0.3` instead of `alpha = 0.5`, but I'm unsure what else might help.